# How to open Chrome with a specific position and size from Terminal? --window-size is not working

Tags: command-line, 18.04, google-chrome, window

I need to open google-chrome with a specific position and location from Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04.
I tried
`google-chrome --window-position=10,10 --window-size=500,300`
But it always opens full screen.
How can I force Chrome open in a small screen with a position?

Thanks in advance.